# chat application with cometd only is good enough?

Tags: xmpp, chat, openfire, cometd

I want to create a web chat application that will just do text chatting. A client will talk to owner. An owner will see the available client to chat with but a client cant see the list of available user he will just click the link and start chat with owner directly.

So i have developed this with cometd and jquery only and its working fine. will that work in real application or should i consider some XMPP server(preferable openfire) also. It is just a text based chat.What are pros and cons of using it with xmpp and without xmpp server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at the [CometD benchmark results](http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/09/cometd-2-4-0-websocket-benchmarks/) to have a glimpse of the CometD performance in a case that is worst than yours: in your case a user just chat with the owner, while in the benchmark a user chats with many others.
The CometD benchmark is actually a normal chat application used to perform the benchmark.

With the WebSocket tranport, CometD easily achieves 50k messages/s for 100k clients with a 4 ms median latency.

My experience is that CometD works really well in real applications, and it's probably simpler than XMPP in your case.

Have a look at the CometD [documentation](http://docs.cometd.org/reference/) and [tutorials](http://docs.cometd.org/tutorials/) to get started.